# Global friend function unable to access private scope even though declared global

Tags: c++, class, function

I'm sure it is something real easy I've overlooked but I'm tearing my hair over this error message. I very seldom use friend functions.

```
error: 'LRESULT Window_Proc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)' should have been declared inside '::'
```

Here's my definition:

```
namespace rayc 
{
    class win32_window: public window {
    public:
        win32_window();
        ~win32_window();

        void show();
        void hide();
        void pump_message();

    private:
        friend LRESULT CALLBACK ::Window_Proc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

        void set_closed(bool);

        HWND hWin;
    };
}
```

I don't quite understand this error message, it is defined as belonging to global scope, is it not?!

Compiling with MinGW-64 TDM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't quite understand this error message, it is defined as belonging to global scope, is it not?!

It is not, unless you have included a forward declaration at the global *namespace* before that `friend` declaration. If a `friend` declaration introduces a new symbol, then such symbol is located at the enclosing *namespace* of the *class* that contains it.

Try adding

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Window_Proc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

at the global namespace, before declaring your *class*.

Comment: Ah... that explains it. I removed :: and put it in the enclosing namespace as a fwd-decl, better anyway. Compiles now, thanks.

Comment: @Skurmedel: You don't need to remove the global namespace qualifier `::`, in fact is good to keep it as long as you _forward declare_ the function.

Comment: I thought it could just live in the namespace anyway, that's why I took it away. Is there good reason to keep the function in global?

Comment: @Skurmedel: No, there is no reason to keep the function global. Its better to keep it at the namespace level, but then there is no need for forward declaring it.

Comment: @Skurmedel: Note that if you remove the `::` the friend declaration  will *befried* `::rayc::Window_Proc` and not `::Window_Proc`

Comment: David Rodríguez - dribeas: You mean it will refer to the friend function rayc::Window_Proc? If so, that was my intention.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: He decided that a namespace function was more appropriate than a global namespace function.